# Qt += webenginewidgets for Mingw

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I want to add web engine widgets to my project so i write `Qt += webenginewidgets` in .pro file. The error i see: *"Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine"*. My Qt version is 6.5, web engine tools are installed.

I have seen that web engine is only supported by MSVC compiler. Is there **any** way to use mingw?

Comment: I just want to believe that something is different now. When did webengine appear? And there is still no support for mingw? i have seen that it's because of chrome and microsoft (didn't pay attention, i was just scrolling someone's discussion)

Comment: Webengine never compiled with MinGW because the underlying chromium sources are not compileable with MinGW. So if you want to get webengine compilable ask the chromium devs to fix it.